# OpenID Connect with embedded resources

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The setup is: we have our user. Our authentication platform (the authorization server). And two different resources. Code authorization flow is used in our setup.

Now resource A embeds stuff from resource B in its pages (with something like an iFrame). Now what we'd like to accomplish is that once the user is authorized for resource A that he will transparantly be able to access the embedded resources from resource B.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

If the authorization server supports Single Sign On (SSO), the embedded page could get its tokens without the user having to enter their credentials. The steps would be like this:

1. User requests Resource A
2. Resource A redirects the user to the OAuth2 server to get tokens
3. The OAuth2 server creates a session for the user (identified by a browser cookie)
4. The user passes authentication and gets redirected to the Resource A page
5. The Resource A page requests Resource B page, so the Resource B goes to point 2, but the point 4 is skipped, because the OAuth2 server already has a session for the user and doesn't ask for the authentication anymore.

Or if your applications don't need access_tokens, just ID tokens, you could pass it from the Resource A to Resource B (e.g. as a URL parameter). In such case, ID tokens should contain both clients (Resource A and B) in its `aud` (audience) parameter.

Comment: We use roles for different applications that determine at the application side if a user has authentication. So the OAuth2 server is only for rough mazed (sorry for the bad translation) authentication. While the roles that is passed through is for fine mazed authentication at the app server. Now passing the identity token will only work if it also contains the role information for application B as well during the process for app A. While in your first process. But yes, with the session in cookie, this is basicly how it would also work with SAML I assume. I'll check that out